# Is there a concise (built-in) way to sample an index from an array by treating values as a probabilities?

Tags: r, random

Suppose I have a vector of probabilities that sum to `1`, such as `foo = c(0.2,0.5,0.3)`.

I would like to sample an index from this vector by treating the values as probabilities.
In particular, I'd like to sample `1` with probability `0.2`, `2` with probability `0.5`, and `3` with probability `0.3`.

Here is one implementation, similar to what I would write in `C`:

```
sample_index = function(probs) {
    r = runif(1)
    sum = 0
    for (i in 1:length(probs)) {
        sum <- sum + probs[i] 
        if (r < sum) return(i)
    }
}
foo = c(0.2,0.5,0.3)
print(sample_index(foo));
```

Is there a more direct / built-in / canonical way to do this in `R`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It always makes me smile and think R is doing a good job when people are looking for a function and repeatedly use its name in their question.

```
foo <- c(0.2, 0.5, 0.3)
sample(x = 1:3, size = 1, prob = foo)
```

Depending on your use case, you could make it a little more general:

```
sample(x = seq_along(foo), size = 1, prob = foo)
```

But do be careful, sample has sometimes convenient but very often unexpected behavior if its `x` argument is of length 1. If you're wrapping this up in a function, check the input length

```
if (length(foo) == 1) foo else sample(x = seq_along(foo), size = 1, prob = foo)
```